# Delays in threads when compositing multiple sets of images using imagemagick with python

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm building an app in a raspberry pi where a user clicks a button and the app takes 3 photos after some count downs and places those 3 photos into a photo template. The first click works as expected, but if I click it the 2nd time, it counts down but it doesn't take a picture until a few seconds later and this delay progresses the more I click the button. The issue is when the app is compositing the 3 photos into the template which take some time to process and it delays the thread that is used to capture the photo. Is this because the bash command in **createPhotoboothImage** function of **ImageService.py** cannot be performed asynchronously or am I doing something wrong with the threads? Any help or suggestions would be great!

**GUIApp.py**

```py
class GUIApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
        self.buttonCountDown = tk.Button(text='Count Down', command=self.capturePhotos)
        self.buttonCountDown.pack()
        self.label = tk.Label(text='Ready!', bg='#3D434F', fg='white', font=('Helvetica', 100, 'bold'))
        self.label.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.captureQueue = queue.Queue()
        self.imageProcessQueue = queue.Queue()
        self.imageService = imageService.ImageService()
        self.cameraService = cameraService.CameraService()
        self.imageCount = 0
        self.images = []
        threading.Thread(target=self.listenToCaptureQueue).start()                
        threading.Thread(target=self.listenToQueue).start()
        threading.Thread(target=self.listenToImageProcessQueue).start()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def countDown(self, seconds):
        for i in range(seconds, 0, -1):
            self.queue.put(i)
            time.sleep(1)
        self.queue.put('SMILE!')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.captureQueue.put(True)        

    def listenToQueue(self):
        while True:
            try:
                if self.queue.empty() == False:
                    s = self.queue.get(0)
                    self.label['text'] = s
                elif self.queue.empty() == True: 
                    pass
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

    def listenToCaptureQueue(self):
        while True:
            try:
                if self.captureQueue.empty() == False:
                    if self.captureQueue.get(0):
                        ## Take a photo               
                        self.label['text'] = 'Please wait...'
                        filePath = self.cameraService.captureImage()
                        self.images.append("%r"%filePath)
                        self.imageCount += 1
                        if self.imageCount < 3:
                            # Start timer again to take photo
                            threading.Thread(target=self.countDown, args=(3,)).start()
                        else:
                            self.buttonCountDown['state'] = 'normal'  
                            self.label['text'] = 'Ready!'
                            self.imageProcessQueue.put(self.images)
                elif self.captureQueue.empty() == True:
                    pass
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

    def listenToImageProcessQueue(self):
        while True:
            try:
                if self.imageProcessQueue.empty() == False:  
                        # Composite the 3 photos to the template                 
                        images = self.imageProcessQueue.get(0)     
                        templatePath = '/home/pi/Documents/Test/template.jpg'
                        destinationPath = '/home/pi/Documents/Test/compositeImage.jpg'
                        self.imageService.createPhotoboothImage(images, templatePath, destinationPath)
                elif self.imageProcessQueue.empty() == True:
                    pass
            except queue.Empty:
                pass           

    def capturePhotos(self):
        self.images = []
        self.imageCount = 0
        self.buttonCountDown['state'] = 'disabled'         
        threading.Thread(target=self.countDown, args=(5,)).start()
```

**ImageService.py**

```py
class ImageService:      
    def createPhotoboothImage(self, images, templatePath, destinationPath):
        cmd = 'convert ' + templatePath + ' \( ' + images[0] + ' -scale "18.5%" \) -geometry +53+401 -composite \( ' + images[1] + ' -scale "9.02%" \) -geometry +1205.5+401 -composite \( ' + images[2] + ' -scale "9.02%" \) -geometry +1205.5+790 -composite ' + destinationPath
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads don't run in parallel in Python due to the Global Interpreter lock, if you relaly want parallel execution, use processes. See for instance the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Comment: That makes sense! Will try this at the end of day.